# How to show the tab in phalcon

Tags: tabs, phalcon, phalcon-routing

I have set of code of tutorial INVO as pre the Phanlcon Official documentation.
I just want to customize the code as per my need, So I wrote some code to prepare a fresh Module.
I created the below files that are needed to create the full module

```
app/controllers/AbcController.php
app/model/Abc.php
app/forms/AbcForm.php
app/view/index.volt
app/view/edit.volt
app/view/search.volt
app/view/new.volt
```

After creating all these file, I am able to runt he module,but In this particular module I am not able to see the tabs having the links.
I think I am missing something, Help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I face the same problem recently, and even the solution is not there in the official documentation of Phalcon.

I came with the solution take reference from another module. There is one file missing in your Code structure that is layout file.

For any module you need to define a layout at least. You have to create a file as below.

```
app/view/layouts/abc.volt
```

In this you have to put the code according to your need that where you want to show the content where center or left align.

{{ elements.getTabs() }}

```
<div align="center">
    {{ content() }}
</div>
```

Here `{{ elements.getTabs() }}` is used to show the tab. Hope you will get the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I also came with the updated answer.

There could be different layout for any view. You just need to define the layout same as the class name. That's It. !

```
app/view/layouts/test.volt
```

or

```
app/view/layouts/test.html
```